# Liberar memoria al cerrar un Forms

Tags: c#

Tengo una aplicacion de escritorio
Al momento de iniciarla el uso de la memoria es de  **302,6 MB** cada vez que abro un formulario nuevo la memoria sube  **3 MB**

El problema es que cada vez que se abre una formulario nuevo sube **3MB** de memoria  y se va llenando, si abres 10 formularios llegas a **2 Megas** de usu y esto no baja asi se cierre el formulario, es decir  incrementa el usu de la memoria por cada formulario abierto y este no baja entoces en el trascurso del dia la app llega a **10GB**

Como se puede matar estos procesos y dejar la memoria libre

he utilizado  **Form.Dispose()** pero no se si lo estoy utilizando mal por que esto no baja esa memoria

¿Como puedo matar estos procesos y dejar la memoria libre de nuevo?

Comment: Hola! Recuerda que las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eso es por  el  recolector de elementos no utilizados: [.NET's garbage collector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/) es automático.

Podrias usar un "using":

```
using (Form miForm = new())
{
    //lo que tengas que hacer con el form
    miForm.Text = "Form 1";
}
```

Al final del bloque se liberará los recursos.

Si no deseas usar el "using" esto te ayudará (dices que tu app llega a 10GB, es bastante memoria)

```
miForm = null; //en realidad no libera la memoria directamente, sino que deja que el GC lo haga antes.
GC.Collect();
```

*Tienes que asegurate de que se llama a **Dispose()** cuando cierras el form. Cito "Dispose se llamará automáticamente si el formulario se muestra mediante el Show método . Si se usa otro método como ShowDialog o el formulario nunca se muestra en absoluto, debe llamarse Dispose a sí mismo dentro de la aplicación."   [Form.Dispose(Boolean) Método.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/)